# Obtaining the single list from iterated string value

Tags: python

I have list

```
pft_list = ['MM5 z no er ers pft\n', 'mm4 no z er efa pft\n',
'mm3 no z er xyz pft\n']
```

I have split the pft_list value by delimiter and fetched the 1st index, I                                             need to have the fetched 1st index into one single list.

```
for x in range(len(pfet_list)): 
    pfet_value = re.split(" ", pfet_list[x])
    print(pfet_value[1])

value would be 
z
no
no
```

Expected Result would got as from each iterated string and it should be converted to single list

```
pft_value1 = [z, no, no]
```

Comment: its code to get the values in the string                                                                      for x in range(len(pfet_list)): 
    pfet_value = re.split(" ", pfet_list[x])
    print(pfet_value[1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use list comprehension :

```
pft_list = ['MM5 z no er ers pft\n', 'mm4 no z er efa pft\n',
'mm3 no z er xyz pft\n']
fList = [m.split(" ")[1] for m in pft_list ]
print(fList)
```

output:

```
['z', 'no', 'no']
```